# PBR with iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, policy-routing

I know question was answered multiple times, but this situation a bit different.

So here is what I have:

- All users must user default gateway on eth0, except one
- That one must *only* use gateway on eth1 and must *not* under any circumstances use eth0

Separately this things easy to implement, but together... With setup it mostly works: 1002 user goes via eth1 and goes nowehere if it's not available. However, some hosts are still routed via eth0. I have no idea why.

Here is my setup:

user@localhost:~$ ip rule

```
0:  from all lookup local
1000:   from all fwmark 0x5 lookup 5
2000:   from all fwmark 0x5 lookup 6
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default`
```

```
user@localhost:~$ ip route list table 5
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.10.0.185 dev eth1
```

```
user@localhost:~$ ip route list table 6

blackhole 0.0.0.0/1
```

```
user@localhost:~$sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo iptables -t mangle -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1002 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x5/0xffffffff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified a route of `0.0.0.0/1`. This [subnet](https://serverfault.com/q/49765/126632) consists of 0.0.0.0 through 127.255.255.255 inclusive. It's not at all clear why you would want to only route *half* of the possible IP addresses. I suspect you meant to route all of it (e.g. `0.0.0.0/0`) instead.

Comment: yup, that was an issue. just noticed that. And pattern of ip address routed via eth0. Apparently, just typing everything here helped me solve it. Thanks.